# rsnapshot stats

Tags: linux, backup, rsnapshot

I'd like to retrieve the following stats from rsnapshot

- files synced
- added files
- modded files
- deleted files

Is there a feature to retrieve these in rsnapshot, or is there another product that's able to do it?

EDIT:
As requested, I'll try to show that I'm not just asking what I want to do without any research.

I wasn't able to locate any rsnapshot feature doing this. Maybe I'm searching in a wrong direction.

So, I've built a not very pretty script, called each time before rsnapshot is ran.
This Perl script stores each file MD5, in order to compare backup files structures between rsnapshot updates. I'm pretty sure it's worthless to show this code here.

I think that keeping an eye on what change on a server, for example, is a useful feature.
So, I'm asking.

@pauska
Most of the time, I'm trying to search for an answer myself, which is not the case here.

Thanks

Comment: "Shopping" questions are frowned upon. Perhaps you could re-write this question to at least give us the impression that you've put any effort into researching this particular usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a perl script that comes bundled with `rsnapshot` called **rsnapreport.pl**, when run it outputs something like this :

```
SOURCE           TOTAL FILES   FILES TRANS      TOTAL MB     MB TRANS   LIST GEN TIME  FILE XFER TIME
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
myhost:/              5176          137      8979.14      7.78   0.978 second   0.000 seconds
```

It won't tell you the deleted and added files, although you will be able to know the numbers by comparing consecutive reports.

Answer (score 2):

If you give "-vi" parameters to the rsync binary, through rsnapshot config file, you will get a list of all operations done on the files. You will have to configure rsnapshot to keep the output of rsync somewhere.